# Draggable marker doesn't work as expected react-native-maps (IOS & Android)

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker, react-native-maps

**I am using react-native-maps to retrieve coordinates and Addresses when the user moves marker on the map.**

**When I move the marker or reposition the marker map gets jerky or the marker doesn't show the correct position in both Android and IOS.**

**onDrag, onDragEnd Doesn't work when the marker position is changed.**

**I am using the below version:**

**"react": "16.13.1"**,
**"react-native": "0.63.4",**
**"react-native-maps": "0.27.1"**

Below is my code.

> ```
> <MapView 
>       style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
>       showsUserLocation
>       showsCompass={true}
>       showsMyLocationButton={true}
>       region = {{
>         longitude:this.state.longitude,
>         latitude:this.state.latitude,
>         longitudeDelta:this.state.longitudeDelta,
>         latitudeDelta:this.state.latitudeDelta
>       }}
>       onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
>       mapPadding={{ top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 0 }}
>       >
>       <Marker 
>           pinColor={'black'}
>           coordinate={{
>               longitude:this.state.longitude,
>               latitude:this.state.latitude,
>               longitudeDelta:this.state.longitudeDelta,
>               latitudeDelta:this.state.latitudeDelta
>           }}
>       />
>      </MapView>
>
>
> onRegionChange = (region) => {
>   this.setState({
>     latitude:region.latitude,
>     longitude:region.longitude,
>     latitudeDelta: 0.0100,
>     longitudeDelta: 0.0100,
> })
> }
> ```

Reference Clip
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1luMj34y-sXzOwSn3ZuF483u60X55zKy7/view?usp=sharing

**I want to implement a Draggable marker and get the coordinates of the marker when it's dragged to a certain location or position on the map without any jerk.**

Comment: Can you provide the full [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code? You can use [snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/) to do this.